# Date Picker not get month and year in edittext

Tags: android, datepicker, android-edittext

I am trying to get selected date from Datepicker in Edittext. But month and year is not updated in Edittext.

Suppose in my Datepicker current date 25/03/2013 and if I change it to 29/02/2011 then it show day correctly (means 29) but month still 03 and year is also still 2013.

I don't understand why my month and year is not updated.

Here is my code:

```
private int pYear=2012;
private int pMonth=04;
private int pDay=12;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
    
                int dayOfMonth) {
            pYear = year;
            pMonth = monthOfYear;
            pDay = dayOfMonth;

            if (pMonth != Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)
                    || pYear != Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
                    
                pMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
                pYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
            }
            updateDisplay();

        }
    };

    
    /** Updates the date in the TextView */
    private void updateDisplay() {
        txtdob.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based so add 1
        .append(pDay).append("/").append(pMonth + 1).append("/")
        .append(pYear).append(" "));
    }

    /** Create a new dialog for date picker */
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(AddBabyActivity.this, pDateSetListener,
                    cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), pDay);

        }
        return null;
    }

imvDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: make sure onDateSet method get called when changing value in DatePickerDialog?

Comment: Day is changing but only month and year not getting change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is because of this peice of code in your ondateset remove the followoing code

```
if (pMonth != Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)
                || pYear != Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)) {

            pMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
            pYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        }
```

what it is saying is if the month and year that came from date setter are not same as the month and year of the current calendar then change them to the current month and current year